# Visual Studio 2015 View Code Behind Shortcut Command from .aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

Is it possible to set a hotkey to navigate to the code behind of a .aspx file? I recently lost this functionality with `F7` after some glitches. I'm looking in the `Tools > Options > Keyboard` settings. The Web Form Editor `View` menu has no command to the .cs file like the CSharp Editor has as `View > Designer`. Even the CSharp Editor `View > Code` seems to be broken.

Nothing in my research seems to fix the issue. Has web forms support been dumped this much?

Comment: It should be `F7` to switch between source and view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `View.ViewCode` command is the one you are looking for. You could try clicking `Reset` then selecting the `Default` keyboard mapping scheme.

Otherwise you can set the global shortcut manually in here:

[image]

Failing that you might have to clear out your Visual Studio user settings:

1. Open Visual studio native tools command prompt.
2. Run `Devenv /ResetSettings General`
3. This will reset the settings to general development profile.

Comment: This eventually worked! I think restarting Visual Studio helped.

Comment: @Tim glad to hear it.